# Response body from post request in angular is empty

Tags: angular, spring, rest

i am doing a post request using Http in angular 7,

code:

```
signInUser(reqData) {
const headerInfo = new Headers({
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                            'X-TIME-ZONE': '+5.30',
                                            'X-DEVICE-ID': '911422351920594',
                                            'X-APP-VERSION': '45',
                                            'X-APP-CHANNEL-NAME': 'ANDROID',
                                            'X-DEVICE-OS-VERSION': '45',
                                            'X-DEVICE-MODEL': 'ANDROID'
                                            });
    const request = this.http.post('server-ip', reqData, {headers: headerInfo});

    request.subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
}
```

i am having backend in spring mvc, and the request is working fine and the server has generated the required response. **In the server log i can see the response json data.**

but when it comes to angular, the response body is empty.

[image: angular response body]

why is this happening?

Comment: Could you try with some http client app like postman  ?

Comment: Is it Cross domain call? I mean the APP domain & API domains are different?

Comment: In postman i am receiving the response data correctly..@Arnaud

Comment: @Rohit.007 APP domain is localhost:4200 and in API domain is another ip.

Comment: This could be the CORS problem, you need to enable the APP domain on API CORS

Comment: This looks like a CORS problem. You need to configure your server to allow it.Edit: Damn  Rohit.007 was faster :)

Comment: I had a similar issue when sending single values not as objects, what is the data that should be arriving ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return the http request.

```
signInUser() {
  .
  .
  return this.http.post('server-ip', reqData, {headers: headerInfo});
}
```

And on your component that requires it, you will subscribe to it in order to return the observable value.

```
this.service.signInUser().subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: the response data is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

Add @CrossOrigin annotation to your rest controller.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class controller{
//..............
}
```

Comment: the backend is spring mvc 3, so no cross origin annotation is available.